# How to stop a service after it has finished its job?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a service which I start from my Activity.
Now the serivce performs some task by starting a new thread from onStartCommand()
I want to stop the service after the thread has finished its job.

I tried using a Handler like this

```
  public class MainService extends Service{

    private Timer myTimer;
    private MyHandler mHandler;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandler = new MyHandler();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new MyTask(), 120000);
        return 0;
    }

    private class MyTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainService.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    }

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.e("", "INSIDE handleMEssage");
            //stopSelf();
        }
    }
```

First it was giving me a warning that if handler class is not static it will cause leaks
After I made it static, stopSelf() can not be called, because its non static.

Is my approach correct or is there a simpler way around ?

Comment: you should use IntentService rather service. It starts automatically in separate thread and stop itself as task completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use IntentService rather service. It starts automatically in separate thread and stop itself as task completes.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService(String name) {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

        // write your task here no need to create separate thread. And no need to stop. 

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to verify whether the service is destroy automatically or not, just override onDestory() sysout something and see the log

Answer (score 3):

Use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) its base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through `startService(Intent)` calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Comment: So you mean stopSelf() is not needed at all in case of Intent Service ?

Comment: yup no need to stop service with IntentService.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
private static class MyHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.e("", "INSIDE handleMEssage");
           MainService.this.stopSelf();;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the standard way of stopping services ?

Comment: This does not work, since you cannot use `this` in a static context. `No enclosing instance of the type MessengerService is accessible in scope`